# Is it haram for woman to choose not marry until die?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, nikah, women

The reason is because of afraid unable to love the husband because already love another man. As far as I know can't enter jannah a woman who doesn't love her husband. While man whom this woman loved is already married so the woman's guardian doesn't agree about the daughter marriage.